# How to retrieve the current day of the week?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, dayofweek

How would I get the current day of the week?
Can some please help me?

Comment: Your question is totally incomplete and unclear, the simplest answer is to look in the calendar?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a text display of the day of the week you can use:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
System.out.println("Today is " + dateFormat.format(new Date()));
```

output:

```
Today is Sunday
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and get the [`DAY_OF_WEEK`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK) field:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Or if you want the day name instead, you can use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.ENGLISH); // override the default Locale
String dayNameInWeek = df.format(today);
```

Comment: However, if you want it in words in the correct language for your Locale, look at DateFormatter.